# PHP Sdk Facebook 4.0 Errors

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have setup my facebook sdk 4.0 script and it is workig fine. Except I'm getting lots of errors. And when i fix one another one displays. I finally patched up all the errors and All i see is this? the errors i seen where just unable to find class files so i required the required files. My domain im using is in my hosts files in my system32 C :\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and all im seing on my website page is what is below?

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => 397011563769936 [first_name] => Fernando [gender] => male [last_name] => Smith [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/397011563769936/ [locale] => en_GB [name] => Fernando Smith [timezone] => 1 [updated_time] => 2014-05-17T01:35:48+0000 [verified] => 1 ) )
```

And this is my index.php, All the files i have is index.php and the folder "Facebook" with all the facebook sdk files in. Its the example provided from facebook so theyre shouldn't be any problems?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)            
   FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('***************','********************************');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://iamawsome.com/fb/' );

try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

// print data
echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
// show login url
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}    
?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I have told you all of that in the post. Im trying to add facebook login. It's all setup on developers.facebook.com and like i said all im seing is that message i have put in my questions.

Comment: If that is the only thing you see things works. That is what the script is suppose to do

Comment: It works! You can access the user data like so: `$graphObject->getProperty('first_name')`